# How to use Axios.post() in a post request containing a json object request-body and a multipart form data (MP4)

Tags: reactjs, axios

Hi I Was wondering how I can send a a single axios post request containing a json object as the request body and also multipart form data (Mp4 file).
In my example I want to send 'details' and 'file'. I have tried sending details and file as 2nd and 3rd arguments to the axios.post() method but from what I can tell axios.post only accepts 2 args.
I have also tried appending the details and then the file, to the form data, but this does not work either.

If I split these into 2 seperate post calls, it works fine, but my application requires these to happen together.

I am getting the following error in my spring console:
[org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryqKyZ0R2SyFeDNCVp;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

Here is the error in my web dev tools console:
xhr.js:210 POST http://localhost:9191/api/123/file/upload 415

Id really appreciate any suggestions

```
const FileUpload = () => {

    const [file, setFile]= useState(null)
    const[details, setDetails] = useState({consent:false, 
                                idConfirmed:false, 
                                label:"", 
                                roundId:""})

    const changeHandler=(e)=>{
        
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
        setDetails(prevDetails=>({
            ...prevDetails,
            consent:true,
            idConfirmed:true,
            label:"test_Label"
        }));
    };

    const handleSubmission=(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();

                    const data = new FormData();

                    data.append("file", file)
                    data.append("file", details)

                    console.log("Data: ", data)


                    axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL_NEW_ROUND_VID}/123/file/upload`, data,
                    {
                        headers:{
                          "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"
                        }
                      })
                    .then(res=>{
                    console.log("Data: ",res.data)
                    console.log("success")
            })


            .catch((e)=>{
                console.log("Error", e)
            })
            //})
        };
```

Here is my rest end point in Springboot:

```
@PostMapping(
   path = "{patientId}/file/upload",
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public void addWardRound(@PathVariable("patientId") String patientId,
                              @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                              @RequestBody WardRequest wardRequest){
      WardRoundService.isFileEmpty(file);
      WardRound round = service.saveRound(wardRequest);
      String roundId = round.getRoundId();
      service.uploadVid(patientId, roundId, file);
   }
```

Comment: You can not send json format data and file as binary data together in same time. so you can send your json data as string with formData structure or send them in 2 separate post request with Promise.all method

Answer (score 0):

you can stringify and send the JSON data. but by using this method you need to parse it in the server!. it could be difficult

The best method is splitting it into 2 APIs

you can merge both API requests in UI by merging both APIs using promise.All
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
const promise1 = axios.get(URL1);
const promise2 = axios.post(URL2, data);

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```

or else if you need to use the result of first API

then call the second API inside the response of first API itself